# Probabilidade em lançamentos de dados

Tags: java

Olá, galera! Estou aprendendo a programar java e me deparei com dois exercícios: no primeiro, eu deveria criar um script que simulasse um lançamento de um dado ; no segundo, um script que lançasse o dado 1 milhão de vezes e mostrasse quantas vezes cada número foi sorteado. Segue o script abaixo:

```
package dado;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dado
{
    public static int dado()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(6)+1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Bem vindo ao cassino! Deseja rolar o dado? [y/n]");
        char resp = entrada.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (resp == 'y')
        {
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + dado());
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Deseja rolar o dado novamente? [y/n]");
                resp = entrada.nextLine().charAt(0);
                switch (resp)
                {
                    case 'y':
                        System.out.println("Resultado: " + dado());
                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        System.out.println("Finalizando...");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Resposta inválida. Responda apenas sim (y) ou não (n)");
                }
            }while(resp == 'y');
        }
        else if(resp == 'r')
        {
            int count1 = 0,
                count2 = 0,
                count3 = 0,
                count4 = 0,
                count5 = 0,
                count6 = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
            {
                int num = dado();
                if (num == 1)
                {
                    count1++;
                }
                if (num == 2)
                {
                    count2++;
                }
                if (num == 3)
                {
                    count3++;
                }
                if (num == 4)
                {
                    count4++;
                }
                if (num == 5)
                {
                    count5++;
                }
                else
                {
                    count6++;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("O dado rolou o número 1 %d vezes.\n", count1);
            System.out.printf("O dado rolou o número 2 %d vezes.\n", count2);
            System.out.printf("O dado rolou o número 3 %d vezes.\n", count3);
            System.out.printf("O dado rolou o número 4 %d vezes.\n", count4);
            System.out.printf("O dado rolou o número 5 %d vezes.\n", count5);
            System.out.printf("O dado rolou o número 6 %d vezes.\n", count6);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Finalizando...");
        }
    }
}
```

O código funcionou corretamente. Contudo, me supreendi com o resultado dos lançamentos sucessivos: o número 6 sempre é sorteado aproximadamente metade das vezes que os outros. 
EX:

```
O dado rolou o número 1 166914 vezes.
O dado rolou o número 2 166765 vezes.
O dado rolou o número 3 167124 vezes.
O dado rolou o número 4 165377 vezes.
O dado rolou o número 5 166884 vezes.
O dado rolou o número 6 833116 vezes.
```

Por que isso acontece? Grato desde já!
Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade, o número 6 não foi sorteado `833116` vezes, é apenas um erro na contabilização das informações: repare que o `else`se refere apenas à condicional `if (num == 5)`, ou seja, caso `num` seja **1**, **2**, **3**, **4** ou **6**, o programa irá acrescer 1 ao `count6`, resultando em um número muito maior.

A propósito, no seu exemplo, o valor correto de `count6` seria `1000000 - 166914 - 166765 - 167124 - 165377 - 166884 = 166936`, um valor normal.

Para solucionar isso, você pode simplesmente substituir o `else` por `if (num == 6)` ou você pode trocar cada um dos `if` e `else` depois do `if (num == 1)` por `else if (num == x)`, em que `x` vai de **2** a **6**.

Comment: Nossa, cara, não me toquei nisso! Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou corrigir o código. Abraço!